# Access specific list of lists in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a piece of data that is made up of List, which in turn has a List. How do I go about displaying a specific LeafSide?

ViewModel:

```
    private List<Leaf> _Leaves = new List<Leaf>();
    public List<Leaf> Leaves
    {
        get { return _Leaves; }
        set
        {
            _Leaves = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Data structure:

```
class Leaf : NotifyBase
{
    private string _LeafNo;
    public string LeafNo
    {
        get { return _LeafNo; }
        set
        {
            _LeafNo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private List<LeafSide> _Side = new List<LeafSide>();
    public List<LeafSide> Side
    {
        get { return _Side; }
        set
        {
            _Side = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //More stuff
}
class LeafSide : NotifyBase
{
    private string _Notes;
    public string Notes
    {
        get { return _Notes; }
        set
        {
            _Notes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //More stuff
 }
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Leaves}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="50" Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Side/Notes}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="50" Header="Punch" Binding="{Binding Side/Punch}"/>
    <!--More-->
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

The above DataGrid will display the first LeafSide perfectly fine, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to display the second side. All examples I can find of DataGrids and nested lists are to display specific values from a list.
I expected something like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="50" Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Side[1]/Notes}"/>
```

to work, but it doesn't.

**EDIT** More info:
I need the DataGrid to display:
[Seperate DataGrids for Leaf and LeafSide[0] displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1sZ.png)
but also for LeafSide[1]

Comment: `{Binding Side[1].Notes}` should work. what if there are more elements?

Comment: @ASh It just generates a blank column with the same number of elements as in LeafNo

Comment: @ASh nevermind, misread your comment. It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASh provided the answer, just reposting so I can mark as Answered

**RIGHT**
    {Binding Side[1].Notes}

**WRONG**
    {Binding Side[1]/Notes}

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a property called 'SelectedSide' in 'Leaf' and use that one for binding

```
  private LeafSide _selectedSide;        
    public LeafSide SelectedSide
    {
        get { return _selectedSide; }
        set { _selectedSide = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSide"); }
    }
```

I guess '[1]' is related to LeafNo. If so set the SelectedSide=Sides[LeafNo]

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="50" Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding SelectedSide.Notes}"/>
```

Comment: I need to display the information in Side for each Leaf. ie: 1,/some notes/  2,/some more notes/  etc